# trouble with z-index not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use z-index to overlay an image onto the body of my website. I have recently started learning css and have been reading all the tutorials on Z-Index(ing) and have never managed to get it to work for myself... The body of my website is an image size 900x500px and I am now trying to overlay some images onto this that I DO NOT want to put in without CSS. I have tried to z-index 0 to the background image and index 1 to the foreground and the other way around, I have tried to change the positions on the images in order to make them work but still I can NOT do it.

The site is here (although it has changed a lot now)

http://tinyurl.com/7x7nzz3

I am trying to overlay an image ontop of the image body.jpg which in the CSS sheet is inside of

```
    #body-wrapper {
background-image: url(images/body.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: center;
    height: 550px;
width: 890;
opacity: 0.4;
```

}

I have removed my failed attempts of z-index from the online site.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I fully understand your problem, but the image that you try to overlay has the style position:absolute; ??

Comment: first of all: Why using alot of background-images for this? Use CSS3's border-radius (http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/). Secondly, since this is an background-image, you can just put another image on top of it by using a regular <img>-Tag

Comment: The background there is no longer a rounded box however thanks for the knowledge. I would like to not use the <img> tag this time as I really want to figure it out the way I want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

For `z-index` to be effective, it must be paired with `position: ___;`.

**Reference**

- [Adding z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/Adding_z-index)

Answer (score 1):

I think you already answered your own question. Why would you want to put a background image on the Z-axis?

Further more, you are correct, only elements can have Z-index, so what you can technically do is, within the body, have a div that contains everything, and have a background image for that div, and that will work. Because you essentially putting the div element on the Z-index and not the image.

```
<style>
#content {
  background-image: url(images/body.jpg);
  position: [absolute:fix];
  z-index: xxx;
}
</style>

<body>
   <div id="content">
     Everything under the sun goes here
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index does not apply to background images, but only to image elements, and I think they have to have absolute (or maybe fixed) positioning too. Background images can not be positioned on the z axis.

You can [play around with this here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must to add a position in order to use z-index , try to add a negative value for background and a higher value for foreground element.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

**HTML**
Laying out your HTML like this should make it work without even using z-index and just using `position:absolute;` because the order of the HTML would make the `img` elements display underneath the rest of the content.

```
<div id="body-wrapper">
  <img src="#" alt="ALT" id="img1" class="overlays">
  <img src="#" alt="ALT" id="img2" class="overlays">
  <img src="#" alt="ALT" id="img3" class="overlays">
  <!-- CONTENT -->
</div>
```

**CSS**
I've added the z-index in here just to show you, but you shouldn't need it. Without the `z-index` the `img` elements should display under the other content because they are before it in the HTML. If the `img` elements came at the very end of `#body-wrapper` they would display on top.

```
#body-wrapper{
 position:relative;
 background-image: url(images/body.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 background-position: center;
 height: 550px;
 width: 890;
 opacity: 0.4;
 z-index:0;
}

.overlays{
position:absolute; //Set the position of img element because z-index needs positioning to work.
//other css
}

#img1{
  top:yourPosition;
  left:yourPosition;
  z-index:100;
}

#img2{
  top:yourPosition;
  left:yourPosition;
  z-index:200;
}

#img3{
  top:yourPosition;
  left:yourPosition;
  z-index:300;
}
```

When you start messing with z-index you almost always end up confusing yourself and it just generally makes the process more complicated. I've got two examples below showing the results. Then second show the opposite of the results you're looking for.

[`<img>` elements first](http://jsfiddle.net/HeyVian/DmGrP/3/)
[`<img>` elements last](http://jsfiddle.net/HeyVian/DmGrP/5/)